# Running multiple applications on a shared process with a shared project library

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, shared

I have a set of applications that run in the same process. These processes have a shared libary, the [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEQQFjAA&url=http://actionbarsherlock.com/&ei=zdrqT8K0Acnc4QTAq7T4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEKyOYK1H-iAiI67o4J8dIPJNL9TA&sig2=IqPFGIGEmlfSZAquyxjTQQ) so that they have the same UI accross different versions of Android. The first time i access elements of the ActionBarSherlock library everything works fine. But when i access the same elements from a different application on the same Android process, i get an error like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  797): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity \
    ComponentInfo{xper.tristram/xper.tristram.XperTristramActivity}: \
    java.lang.ClassCastException: xper.common.CommonView cannot be cast to xper.common.CommonView
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: \
    xper.common.CommonView cannot be cast to xper.common.CommonView
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at xper.tristram.XperTristramActivity.onCreate(XperTristramActivity.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
E/AndroidRuntime(  797):    ... 11 more
```

The above block code is copy pasted from [this site](http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/two-android-applications-a-shared-ui-element-and-a-shared-process-a-tale-of-classloaders-and-confusion/). A colleague of mine found out this site that describes the root of the problem which is that there are two different instances of the loaded class of the shared library by the two Class Loaders one for each application. The author of the site provides a workaround, that is to override of the creation of shared views by the LayoutInflater, using the method LayoutInflater.setFactory(). My question is, if there is any other solution that doesn't require to override core methods of the Android library which in my opinion can be error prone and not efficient.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The "other solution" is to not "have a set of applications that run in the same process".

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot change the logic of the project since every different app works as a "plugin" for the main app.

Comment: Plugins do not need to run in the same process. They can communicate via inter-process communication (broadcasts, commands to services, binding to services, `ContentProvider`, etc.).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick replies!

Comment: I know that content providers can solve my problem however i didn't knew that from the time i started writing the app with my colleagues so this is a major and time consuming change since the project is now huge and unfortunately we don't have the time to do that (strict time schedule that is not in our hands to change). Also i know this is not recommended by Android, but since they give you the option i think is something that can be used.

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't use it. I am saying that your problem stems from your decision, and that trying to share classes between the different things running in your process will be troublesome. This sort of issue has plagued Java developers for a long time and is ordinarily not an issue in Android. Even if you are running them all in one process, the closer you can get to an API between pieces that *resembles* IPC (e.g., sticks to primitives), the smoother that integration is likely to become.

Comment: The shared process is something that will be avoided in the future but for now, unfortunately, it cannot change (for the reasons mentioned earlier). So, from your feedbacks i get that there is no any other possible workaround for my problem?

Comment: I am not even convinced that your planned workaround will actually work, though you are certainly welcome to try it. I know of no alternatives, besides redesigning your API as noted above.

Comment: Ok, i will try the method suggested from that web site. I will post any progress or problems i stumble upon following that workaround. Anyways, thank you for your feedback:)